# While loop and tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define a function that returns the sum of all the integers between, and including, the two given numbers but I am having trouble with the last line of code, which is down below. For example, the user inputs two integers such as (2,6) and the function will add everything together, 2+3+4+5+6=20.  I cannot figure out how to make my function start at input(x) and end at input(y).  Also, I want to use the while loop.

```
def gauss(x, y):
    """returns the sum of all the integers between, and including, the two given numbers

    int, int -> int"""
    x = int
    y = int
    counter = 1
    while counter <= x:
        return (x + counter: len(y))
```

Comment: I tried to fix your code formatting, but `x = int` etc. isn't really making sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using sum as below:

```
In [2]: def sigma(start, end):
   ...:     return sum(xrange(start, end + 1))
   ...: 

In [3]: sigma(2, 6)
Out[3]: 20
```

In case you want to use a while loop, you can do:

```
In [4]: def sigma(start, end):
   ...:     total = 0
   ...:     while start <= end:
   ...:         total += start
   ...:         start += 1
   ...:     return total
   ...: 

In [5]: sigma(2, 6)
Out[5]: 20
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def gauss(x, y):
    """returns the sum of all the integers between, and including, the two given numbers
    int, int -> int"""

    acc = 0 # accumulator
    while x <= y:
        acc += x
        x += 1

    return acc
```

Aside: A better way is to not use `sum` or`range` or loops at all

```
def gauss(x, y):
    return (y * (y + 1) - x * (x - 1)) // 2
```